# How to reference an object in a table in Lua by its name

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

This seems like a very straightforward question, but I haven't been able to turn up an answer.  I am adding game objects to a table in Lua like this:

```
local lock = GameObject {
 -- object values and methods
table.insert(objects, lock)
```

But despite a lot of google searching and reading through the Lua documentation, I cannot figure out how to reference these objects by their names.  I think it's because there is a very specific syntax to do so.  If anyone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do something like this instead of table.insert. Objects will still be a table.

```
objects = {}
objects.lock = {}
objects.lock2 = {}
```

If you then execute

```
for key, value in pairs(objects) do
  print(key,value)
end
```

You will get the output

```
lock2   table: 0x1af3310
lock    table: 0x1af3870
```

---

**Further explanation**

In you question(not the solution above) lock is only the variable name given to it, it is not the name of the index.

In this code snippet, you can see that the items being inserted into objects do not have the variable name recorded within `objects.` `objects` is storing an int as the key, and then the inserted table as the value.

```
objects = {}
local lock = {}
local lock2 = {}

 -- object values and methods
table.insert(objects, lock)
table.insert(objects, lock2)

for key, value in pairs(objects) do
  print(key,value)
  print(type(value))
end
```

prints

```
1   table: 0x131b590
table
2   table: 0x131b540
table
```

[test it on repl](https://repl.it/languages/lua)

Comment: Thanks!  I have a few follow up questions. 1) My program uses the pairs function in many places to react to objects.  Will that still work with your suggested method, ie. "objects.lock".  2) If not, is it possible to grab those key integers (0x131b590) on creation and store them somewhere for quick reference?  3) Does anyone have experience with Penlight?  I've heard that it is a life saver, but I don't quite know how to get started.  When I require it, I get an error message that "No pl.pretty" in Love directories.  And I can't tell how to download install it from the PL page on github.

Comment: 1) Yes it still works, the key in that for-loop output would be 'lock' instead of 1 or 2. 2) 0x131b590 refers to the value, not the key 3) I don't have any experience with Penlight.

And if the answer solved your question, could you mark it correct please? Thank you

Comment: @DavidGallagher I updated my answer to show how part 1 works

Comment: Thanks again @Sam . I still don’t have enough points on Stack Overflow to cast a public vote for answer, but I’ll be sure to mark your answer as soon as I do